# How do we do something in js before sessionStorage is cleared?

Tags: javascript, session

What I want to do is store the data fetched from google tag manager in dataLayer and store it in database at the end of every session.

Comment: Answer to the only question you asked is easy: you put the code you want to run before clearing sessionStorage before the code that clears sessionStorage - how do you identify "the end of every session"?

Comment: @Bravo - IMO, OP is asking about the events when session storage is cleared, for eg. close of a tab/browser.

Comment: oh, sendBeacon or fetch with appropriate settings then

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.